# How to animate UITableViewCell XIB-subclass contents when in editing mode?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableViewCell that I created in an XIB and hooked up to the .h and .m. The cell is being displayed in a UITableView that needs the ability to go into editing mode. When it goes into editing mode, however, the cell contents don't move or resize. Also, if and when the Delete button appears, the contents do not shift. I realize similar questions have been asked here, but I haven't found any that had the correct answer or an answer for this specific situation.

Comment: Did you setup `autoresizingMask` (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/autoresizingMask) properties to `UIViews` in your custom `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: Yes. It would seem that when working with an XIB, the the subviews aren't correctly added to the contentView.